# Tornado will import in Jupyter but not VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, tornado

I can import Tornado in my Jupyter Notebook without any problem but when I try to do so in VS Code I get the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'`.

I installed Tornado using Anaconda, `conda install -c conda-forge tornado`, but I don't know how that could make a difference between Jupyter and VS Code. Any ideas how I can get Tornado running on VSC?

Comment: check your interpreter in VSC.  Are you sure its pointing to the same Python or VirtualEnv as Jupyter is?

Comment: Thanks, I needed to change the interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select correct python interpreter in visual studio code, Below link might be helpful in selecting the correct python interpreter for your code.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Also, I believe you should use virtual environments for managing the package efficiently, to integrate the right virtual environment in Jupiter notebook

you can follow this https://www.slideshare.net/dhineshsunderganapathi/intro-tovenvpy3?qid=8f764e4a-12d4-4280-841f-e4314afcd7ab&v=&b=&from_search=1

Let me know how this goes.

Comment: Thanks, I was not using the right interpreter. It is working now in VSC